# How can I skip empty pages while scraping in R using rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the spotify charts from https://spotifycharts.com/regional/nl/daily/. So far everything went well until I tried scraping multiple pages per day. On certain days there is no data available on spotifycharts. Is there some kind of R function that skips empty pages or ignores the error of no available data on a page and keeps on scraping the next page? Maybe even adds NA values to my dataframe if there is no data available to scrape?

I tried using a tryCatch but to no avail. the snippet below shows my working code (up until 2017-05-30 where there is no spotifychart data to scrape on the page).

```
#import libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

#get URL
url <- "https://spotifycharts.com/regional/nl/daily/"

#combine elements from one page
get_one_page <- function(url) {
  
  #scrape all elements
  html <- read_html(url)
  
  #wait 2 seconds for each request
  Sys.sleep(2)
  
  #get all song positions
  position <- html %>% 
    html_nodes(".chart-table-position") %>%
    html_text()
  
  #get all song names
  songs <- html %>% 
    html_nodes("strong") %>%
    html_text()
  
  #get all artist names
  artists <- html %>%
    html_nodes(".chart-table-track span") %>%
    html_text()
  
  #get all streams
  streams <- html %>%
    html_nodes("td.chart-table-streams") %>%
    html_text()
  
  #get date of chart
  date <- html %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div/div/div/div/span/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div") %>%
    html_text()
  
  #get region of list
  region <- html %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div/div/div/div/span/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div") %>%
    html_text()
  
  
  #return table
  url_data <- tibble(position = position, songs = songs, artists = artists, streams = streams, date = date, region = region)
  return(url_data)

}

#scrape multiple pages
scrape_write_table <- function(url) {
  
  list_of_dates <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2020-09-20"), by="days")
  list_of_pages <- str_c(url, list_of_dates)
  
  list_of_pages %>%
    map(get_one_page) %>%
    bind_rows()
}

#create dataframe
spotifycharts_df <- scrape_write_table(url)
view(spotifycharts_df)

#create CSV
#write_csv(spotifycharts_df, "spotifycharts_data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to scrape the drop-down list since it only contains the dates have available data, then use those dates to scrape tracks data:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://spotifycharts.com/regional/nl/daily/"
dates <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class='chart-filters-list']/div[@data-type='date']/ul/li") %>% html_attr("data-value")
spotifycharts_df <- 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    dates,
    function(date) {
      print(date) # add this line to monitor the scraping process
      tracks <- read_html(paste0(url, date)) %>%
        html_nodes("table.chart-table > tbody > tr")
      data.frame(
        date = as.Date(date), 
        position = tracks %>% html_node(xpath = "./td[@class='chart-table-position']") %>% html_text() %>% as.integer(),
        title = tracks %>% html_node(xpath = "./td[@class='chart-table-track']/strong") %>% html_text(),
        artist = tracks %>% html_node(xpath = "./td[@class='chart-table-track']/span") %>% html_text() %>% stringr::str_sub(start = 4),
        image = tracks %>% html_node(xpath = "./td[@class='chart-table-image']/a/img") %>% html_attr("src"),
        link = tracks %>% html_node(xpath = "./td[@class='chart-table-image']/a") %>% html_attr("href"),
        streams = tracks %>% html_node(xpath = "./td[@class='chart-table-streams']") %>% html_text() %>% gsub(",", "", .) %>% as.integer()
      )
    }
  )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Seems the logical way to scrape the dates instead of creating a list of my own. I don't have the time to check your code right now but I will try this tomorrow. If it works for me I will accept your answer. Thanks again for taking the time!

Comment: @JotteSmit Cut the `dates` vector to try first. Scrape all the dates from 2017 can take hours.

Comment: I scraped the dates in  may 2017 (where it previously gave an error) and it works like a charm! Thank you very much for this elegant solution and the time you took for this!!